# search files from a list and delete them

Tags: bash

I have a list of files without their path. They are mp4 like E16743.mp4.  I need to search  each file in a directory using the list and delete them. If I type `cat list.txt | while read f; do echo $f; done` it displays each filename one after the other. When I type `cat list.txt | while read f; find . -name "$f"; done` it doesn't display the files it found in the directory. So when I try to delete the files from the list by entering `cat list.txt| while read f; do find . -name "$f" -delete; done` nothing get deleted.
I also cleaned up the files so that I have no carriage returns left in it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could your list have DOS newlines? If so it's looking for a file _actually_ named `E16743.mp4$'\r'`, but the `$'\r'` is invisible when it's printed. Use `dos2unix` to convert the file to have normal UNIX newlines.

Comment: You can debug this by running `bash -x yourscript` so you can see the _actual_ `find` commands being run, and compare them to what you expect. Also, `while IFS= read -r f` will correctly handle names that contain backslashes (that's what the `-r` is for), or start or end with whitespace (that's what the `IFS=` fixes).

Comment: BTW, it's also better to put `<list.txt` after the `done` instead of putting `cat list.txt |` at the beginning; this avoids the issues discussed in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), and having a "real" seekable file handle lets `read` operate in a more efficient way (where it reads a larger buffer and then rewinds to the line ending, instead of needing to read only one byte at a time to make sure it doesn't go past the end)

Comment: Try `cat -vet list.txt` in order to see any *"Windowsy"* Carriage Returns in your file.

Comment: Replace `cat list.txt` with `dos2unix < list.txt`.

Comment: Thank you. I have used different ways including < list.txt but this doesn't change the problem I am having where the files do not get deleted.

Comment: @Charles Duffy  Thank you very much. I did cat -vet and got ^M$ at the end of each line. So I need to clean this up and try again.

Comment: Right -- it _should_ just be a `$` at the end of each line; the `^M` is the character also known as `\r`. (The `<list` was a performance suggestion, not anything to do with fixing the problem at hand; I wouldn't have said "btw" / "by the way" if it were directly responsive as opposed to an aside).